# Blender 2.8: I can't enter into Fly mode to move the camera

Tags: camera

I have a spanish keyboard, so I can't insert the "shift + grave accent" key combination. My keyboard can't insert the "grave accent" character itself.

Comment: That sounds similar to the issue reported here: https://developer.blender.org/T66607

Answer (score 0):

(With the default key bindings) If you hold grave/backtick, it brings up the pie menu for various views. However, if you just tap it, it should bring you into fly mode.